# Postgresql error when creating extension :Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libtiff/lib/libtiff.5.dylib

Tags: postgresql, postgis, gdal

I am trying to install PostGIS and spacial libraries for Postgres as per [GeoDjango docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/gis/install/#homebrew) . after installation I tried creating PostGIS extension for my database but I get the following error

```
psql postgistest -c 'create extension postgis;'

ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/local/lib/postgresql/rtpostgis- 2.4.so": 
dlopen(/usr/local/lib/postgresql/rtpostgis-2.4.so, 10):
Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libtiff/lib/libtiff.5.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/gdal/lib/libgdal.20.dylib
Reason: image not found
```

there were similar issues for other libraries but nothing works for me. I followed this [solution](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/33462) but it didn't work for me. I also tried reinstalling all geospatial libraries, Postgres, postgis and tried brew update but nothing worked.

Comment: Post title talks about libtiff, while body libgdal. So, which one is it?

Comment: actually i posted full error and the error says libtiff Library not loaded @mvp

Comment: In SQL you can query extensions loaded with

    select * from pg_extension;

You can list available extensions (installed) with

   SELECT * FROM pg_available_extensions;

If  postgis is not installing, what version of Postgresql are you running? Is it a compatable version?

Comment: i am running postgres 10.5. @Slumdog